# Why Python adds extra characters in string?

Tags: python, string, url

I need to change just a tiny bit of a url but Python adds extra stuff, specifically this: '*amp;*' bits, that messes up the url address generating a error as the url does not exist!
Example:

```
specialinfo = str(42)
my_url = 'https://www.justexample.com/thingshere/morestuff/ordinaryurlthing?mybit=' + specialinfo + '&endofmyurlbits'
print(my_url)
```

What I get is:

```
https://www.justexample.com/thingshere/morestuff/ordinaryurlthing?mybit=42&amp;endofmyurlbits
```

instead of what I expect:

```
https://www.justexample.com/thingshere/morestuff/ordinaryurlthing?mybit=42&endofmyurlbits
```

If I exclude the '*https:*' bits it works! Example:

```
specialinfo = str(42)
my_url = 'www.justexample.com/thingshere/morestuff/ordinaryurlthing?mybit=' + specialinfo + '&endofmyurlbits'
print(my_url)
```

Now I get:

```
www.justexample.com/thingshere/morestuff/ordinaryurlthing?mybit=42&endofmyurlbits
```

I'm using with:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://'+my_url) as remote:
    data = remote.read()
```

And it is working. However, the question remains! Why adding '*https://*' in the string does the above mentioned?

ps.: I am using Python 3 with Jupyterlab in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import html
html.unescape('https://www.justexample.com/thingshere/morestuff/ordinaryurlthing?mybit=42&amp;endofmyurlbits')
```

This should work.
This happens because HTML only accepts utf-8 and tries to convert all non utf-8 characters. You can unescape this by applying what I just showed.

I hope it helped